# How to pass command line arguments to script in v8?

Tags: javascript, v8

After ./shell my.js -- 3, it stil says that "arguments is not defined", which I suppose should contain '3'.

Comment: just "print(arguments);"

Answer (score 0):

As per http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1477, this feature was broken for a while, and then fixed.  Are you running the latest version?

== EDIT ==

As pointed out by @dalibocai, the V8 `shell` command doesn't support the `--` notation to pass arguments, the `d8` script interpreter does however.

Comment: I see the problem. Shell doesn't support it. If I use d8, it works fine.